# Advanced Custom Fields & Admin Color Schemer; change color of ACF buttons

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I use Admin Color Schemer to style my customers' WordPress admin panel, but it doesn't affect the buttons from Advanced Custom Fields' custom fields.

How would I change the plugin to include these buttons?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom styling on the admin panel through the `admin-bar.css` stylesheet, which you can find in your WP installation under `/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.css`