# advanced custom fields wordpress custom class

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom field in ACF which is a button that I need to change to a different colour based on what page they are on, so for example

Page 1 - Button needs to be blue
Page 2 - Button needs to be red

But they both use the same ACF button.

Is there a way to do this or do I need to create individual ones of each page?

Comment: Refer this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366193/advanced-custom-fields-admin-color-schemer-change-color-of-acf-buttons

Comment: that seems to be only relating to the admin panel of wordpress? or am i reading it wrong?

Comment: You can give separate class for those buttons, while creating page in wordpress Advance Custom Fields editor. Then you can easily override button colour based on class in style.css.

Comment: You could also create a colour picker ACF on each page and use this to select the colour for that page. Just print out the colour with some inline styles and button will be coloured as the user selects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress adds unique classes to the body element of each page/post - and this can help you achieve what you need.

First inspect the body element of your pages - Page 1 probably has a class `page-1` and Page 2 probably has a class `page-2`.

Then you can use CSS rules to target your buttons:

```
/* Target Page 1 Button */
.page-1 .btn {
  background-color: red;
}
/* Target Page 2 Button */
.page-2 .btn {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the WordPress `is_page()` function to add a unique class to your buttons determined by page:

```
<?php
// e.g. in functions.php
function extraButtonClass() {
  // Target by page slug or ID
  if(is_page('page-1')) {
    return ' red';
  } elseif(is_page('page-2')) {
    return ' blue';
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

// In template:
<button class="btn<?php echo extraButtonClass(); ?>">My Button</button>
```